# Running ILWIS commands from DOS (cmd) prompt?

Tags: command-line, ilwis

ILWIS commands from DOS (cmd) prompt

I am able to run MapDrainageNetworkExtraction from ILWIS's command prompt interface.

However, I now want to run it from a DOS (cmd) prompt like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ILWIS 3.3 Academic>outmap=MapDrainageNetworkExtraction(flowaccilwis.mpr, 60);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: give any alternative ways to run

Comment: I am having doubt like i can access firefox from cmd like that is there any way ?

Comment: Give any answer plz